# xcorr command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

According to the documentation, there is no convenient `'same'` option for the `xcorr` command like there is for `conv` to keep the output the same size as one of the inputs.

Is there a way to get around this problem besides calculating the appropriate indices and talking a subarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's no such thing for `xcorr`, and the problem is that even if you specify `MAXLAG` you will get a vector of length 2*MAXLAG+1, so it's always going to be odd. If your input signal is odd, you can call `xcorr( a,b, (length(a)-1)/2 );`. If you're delaing with even or arbitrary lengths, I'm afraid you'll have to use subarray calculations.`However, to be clever you can use a similar trick, and simply say

```
R = xcorr( a,b, floor(length(a)/2) );
R = R( 1:length(a) );
```